# How can Scarlet Witch hold off Thanos?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, infinity-stones

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, Scarlet Witch is forced to

> destroy the Mind Stone and kill the Vision in the process

While she is in the process of doing that, Thanos attacks her, wielding a gauntlet with five of the six Infinity Stones. Somehow, she is able to use her powers to hold him back. Scarlet Witch's powers came from the Mind Stone. Knowing that, how is she able to hold back Thanos? He should have significantly more power than her, given the fact that his power is currently coming from five Infinity Stones.

Comment: “Scarlet Witch's powers came from the Mind Stone.” Is that true? I can’t remember hearing/seeing it stated anywhere.

Comment: "I don't know what this is. Not really. I know it's not of this world, that it powered Loki's staff, gave you your abilities. But its true nature is a mystery and yet it is part of me." Vision says this in Civil War.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that :)

Comment: I guess we should assume that if her powers come from the Mind Stone he does not possess, he can't control/overcome her power using the gauntlet. Each of the stones was different so it doesn't mean that five stones beat one since their powers were not same.

Comment: Wanda had more time to explore her powers, so she could use it more efficiently. Remember, how Thanos failed to stop Stormbreaker in the end despite the fact that Infinity Stones are more powerful. Stormbreaker could, in theory, be stopped in mid-air or turned into bubble etc.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: see also the mid-credits scene in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you say, Wanda's powers derive from the Mind Stone.  In the MCU, she and Pietro were experimented on by Strucker using Loki's staff, which ultimately turned out to be a housing for the Mind Stone.  This was established in the post-credits scene for *The Winter Soldier*, and possibly in some dialog at the beginning of *Age of Ultron*.

As Thanos approaches Wanda, he attempts to use the gauntlet as a shield, while at the same time using the Space Stone to bend space, attempting to divert her powers. You can see her power and the aura of the Space Stone basically sliding over one another. The Space Stone *should* be able to easily divert the beam or even pop her to the moon with barely a second thought, but in this case it seems to be struggling to fight against her.

I suspect the reason for this is that in the MCU, *the power of the stones can't be used against one another directly*.  Thanos can't use the gauntlet against Wanda directly because the stones view her as an extension of the Mind Stone.  Wanda, on the other hand, can use her power against Thanos because he's just a dude with a gauntlet.

Consider the previous scene on Titan.  Thanos says to Dr Strange, referring to the Time Stone

> You're full of tricks wizard, but you never once used your greatest weapon.

That may be because Strange, having looked into the future, knew the dangers or difficulties of wielding the power of the stones against each other.

On the other hand, it's also worth noting that in the comics, Wanda is far, *far* more powerful than the typical usage of her powers would suggest.  She had the ability to essentially re-write reality, at one point altering the entire Earth into a place where mutants were the ruling class, with normal humans as an underclass, essentially re-writing the prior half century or more of history.

Comment: `Wanda, on the other hand, can use her power against Thanos because he's just a dude with a gauntlet.` You say the power of the stones couldn't be used against each other, but then say that Wanda could us her powers against Thanos because he's just a dude in a gauntlet. But surely Thanos is using the power of the other stones, and therefore Wanda's action would also be rendered useless.

Comment: @Edlothiad I think what Jherico is saying there is Wanda isn't trying to do anything to the stones, just Thanos, as Thanos isn't imbued with the the power of the stones but is merely using them then there is no issue using it against him, if she used it against the gauntlet that might have caused issues... though this theory is flawed as a few moments later Wanda using her powers shatters the mind stone in Visions forehead.

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn Being able to use a Stone against *itself* doesn't necessarily contradict the theory that you can't use a Stone against any of the other Stones.

Comment: Strange didnt use the time stone because he didnt have it, it was hidden away. The risk of using the stone and failing and then losing it vs the risk of losing but Thanos still not being able to get the stone.

Comment: This is too speculative and doesn't take Thanos's minimal force application attitude.

Comment: The mind stone have been used against the space stone in the first Avengers movie (in the form of the scepter and the tesseract)

Comment: If you're talking about the way the scepter was used to pierce the shield on the portal generator in Avengers, I think that actually is in favor of my point of view.  The space stone was generating a shield to keep out everything, but was specifically unable to keep out the mind stone (as the scepter).

Comment: "the power of the stones can't be used against one another directly" I disagree since in endgame it's pretty much that (I don't want to spoil)

Answer (score 7):

Wanda is one of the most powerful Mutants in the comic book universe and this was a way of demonstrating her power in the MCU, but also in the comics Wanda's power is very much linked to her emotional state. Grief leads her to change the reality of the whole world, anger leads her to almost destroy it.

Wanda has shown this link between emotion and power in the MCU. When Hawkeye has his talk with a scared Wanda when she then gets her bravery and focus she can destroy Ultron's drones easily, later when her Brother dies she again sends out an energy wave that destroys a number of Ultron's drones, a power she hadn't demonstrated earlier. Then she goes to one of the main drones and easily destroys him by ripping out his heart, again showing how anger makes her powers stronger. In *Civil War* when she pushes Vision under ground while escaping the Avengers HQ she is again showing emotion, anger in this situation, regret at having to do this, a bit of sorrow.

So that scene with Vision and Thanos is the culmination of several moments in the MCU where they have painted a picture that Wanda's Powers are directly linked to her emotional state. That is the most emotional position she has been in, she is having to use her powers to destroy the "Man" she loves to save the Universe. A choice she does not want to make. She is suffering from grief, anger and anguish all at once but also feeling the love from Vision. All that allows her to unlock and tap into her true power.

Now as to why she can act against the Mind Stone, yes the Mind stone was used to give her her powers but I always saw it as the Mind Stone having given Strucker the knowledge to change the twins, it didn't give them powers it more likely allowed him to create a machine to generate them. This is how it has worked throughout the MCU giving knowledge and allowing people to unlock there potential but lose sight of the ethics of there choices in the pursuit of knowledge. So she is not acting against her own power, she has her own power the Mind Stone simply allowed that power to be unlocked. Otherwise both twins would have had the same abilities.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, Wanda didn't hold Thanos back. He let her think he did for an easier win.

There are main 2 factors in play here.  The gauntlets power and Thanos's pride.  Wanda's power is a tertiary factor. Spoilers ahead!

> In order to use the gems together, you have to be a being who can channel the huge amount of power that flows through it.  Separately, they don't have the same energy drain.  Thanos is one of these beings as he has focused on increasing his personal power over the years, at least, in the comics he has.  This is later confirmed in Endgame when Thanos said he used the gauntlet to destroyed the gems and it nearly killed him.  Also when Tony used the gauntlet and died.

Secondly, Thanos's downfalls is pride.  Thanos is a master tactician (or overly cautious) and knew he could reverse time and take the stone at any moment.

In his pride, he let others think they have a chance to win, (when they don't) just to cause despair.  Thanos revels in defeating his opponents to the point of despair including the Avengers who face him before Wanda does.  That's Thanos's thing, he's Death's Champion, a nihilist and when he defeats you, he wants you to know it, without a doubt, that you were defeated before the battle started.  Like Dr Strange said "1 in 14,000,605 possible futures."

When facing Wanda, he only channeled enough power to shield himself until Wanda finished off the Vision herself.  Then he brought the Vision back, casually backhanded her and took the final soul stone, to her despair.  Since her power was spent, she was easier to deal with compared to if he went head on with her and would have to channel even larger amounts of power through the gauntlet.  He needed to use as little as possible to channel the large amount used in removing half the universe.

Later, he even went so far as to mock Thor and say "You should have went for the head."  Then snapped his fingers and completed his task, to Thor's despair.

So he let Wanda win and then showed her it was all for nothing.  As he said, "I am inevitable."  Such is Death and it's Champion.